# Remove word after last dash with regex in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve defined string `word-word-word-test` and I want to remove the `-test` (all behind the last dash). How can I do that with a RegEx?

My `/-.*$/` works only if there are no other dashes in the string.

Comment: What language are you using?  The regex is mostly language-independent (something like `-[^-]*$`), but the command to execute the replacement is language-dependent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `-[^-]*$` to replace "dash followed by zero or more non-dash characters anchored to the end of the string."  You may also just want to use `(-test)*$` to replace all `-test` instances at the end of the string.

Comment: +1 but I think the first half of your question is the correct part.